# How to properly add addeventlistener?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I try add to array with image event listener which catch load event and it's works. But sometimes i parameter passed to the decrement function is the same for all requests

```
var imgNumb = vectors.length;
function decrement(i, type){
    imgNumb--;
    console.log('Processed '+ type+' nr: ' + i + '. Left: '+ imgNumb);
}
for(var i in vectors)
{
    if(jQuery('#canvas-'+i).length != 0){
    var tempCont = document.getElementById('canvas-'+i);
    tempImage[i] = new Image();
    alert(i);
    tempImage[i].addEventListener('load', function(){
        decrement(i, 'canvas');
    }, false);
    type[i] = 'canvas';
       tempImage[i].src = tempCont.toDataURL();
    }
}
```

for example i get:

```
Processed canvas nr: 1. Left: 2
Processed canvas nr: 2. Left: 1
Processed canvas nr: 2. Left: 0
```

but alert (if it isn't inside handler) always return correct key number.

Comment: This is a classic closure problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating a function in a loop which is dependent on the loop variable. All functions reference **the same** `i`. You have to introduce a new scope (by calling a function) to capture the current value of the variable:

```
(function(index) {
    tempImage[index].addEventListener('load', function(){
        decrement(index, 'canvas');
    }, false);
}(i));
```

Here we use an *immediate* or *self-invoking function*.

---

[Don't use `for...in` to iterate over arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#Description). Use a normal `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

@Felix's answer is correct, but I thought I might show an alternative solution that might be more readable:

```
var imgNumb = vectors.length,
    tempImage = [];

function decrement(i, type) {
    imgNumb--;
    console.log('Processed ' + type + ' nr: ' + i + '. Left: ' + imgNumb);
}

$.each(vectors, function(i, element) {
    var $canvas = $('#canvas-' + i);
    if ($canvas.length) {
        tempImage[i] = $('<img/>', {
            src: $canvas.get().toDataURL(),
            load: function() {
                decrement(i, 'canvas');
            }
        });
        type[i] = 'canvas';
    }
});
```

It's not clear in the question if `vectors` is a jQuery object or a plain JS array, so I've taken the safe assumption and used [`$.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/). If `vectors` *is* a jQuery object, you can use [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) instead.

Other fixes:

- [Don't use `for... in` to iterate over arrays.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#Description)
- Just check the truthiness of `jQuery('#canvas-' + i).length`
- You're using jQuery - why use `document.getElementById()`?
- Again, you're using jQuery - why use `addEventListener()`?

Comment: +1 I didn't see that the OP is using jQuery... then it can definitely be improved a lot :)

Comment: Unfortunately you code doesn't work. Firstly what is that ->`$canvas.get().toDataUrl()`? 2nd, this `$('<img/>', {
            src: $canvas.get().toDataURL(),
            load: function() {
                decrement(i, 'canvas');
            }
        });` 
create a jQuery object, and canvas drawImage method throw the exception.

Comment: Calling [`.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get) on a jQuery object returns the underlying DOM element. To further solve your problem, it would help if you could show a more complete example of your code. I don't see anywhere that you're calling `drawImage()` on the canvas.